# Cuenta individual Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Estoy intentando crear una cuenta en Google Cloud Platform con mi cuenta personal pero veo que si selecciono como país España en el tipo de cuenta únicamente me deja seleccionar Empresa.

Según leo aquí https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-way-to-use-Google-Cloud-Platform-as-individual-in-Europe y aquí https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6090602?hl=en hubo cambios debido al IVA en Europa, por lo que sólo puedes crear una cuenta con propósitos empresariales. Me parece un fastidio ya que imagino que muchas personas como yo, querrán poder probar la plataforma simplemente para formarse en ella o crear una aplicación sin fines lucrativos.

Entonces, hay dos opciones:

- Crear la cuenta seleccionando España y metiendo un nombre de empresa inexistente. No sé si esto es muy legal. Además lo he probado y me rechaza la transacción con la tarjeta. ¿Tiene que ser una tarjeta vinculada a una empresa o algo así?
- Crear la cuenta seleccionando Estados Unidos. Así puedes seleccionar cuenta individual. No lo he probado. ¿Es posible o habrá algún tipo de problema?

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: Creo que en la actualidad ya esta solucionado eso.